# When changing data to Mongodb using the put method, it gives an error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use method 'PUT' in my code. I send {"name":"newTestName"} in the postman using method 'PUT'. Postman writes : "Internal Server Error" and Console writes error.

Server.js:

```
app.put("/artists/:id", function(req, res) {
  db.collection("artists").updateOne(      
    { _id: ObjectID(req.params.id) },
    { name: req.body.name },
    function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.sendStatus(500);
      }
      res.sendStatus(200);
    }
  );
```

Console:

```
{ MongoError: the update operation document must contain atomic operators.

driver: true,
name: 'MongoError',
[Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in an `updateOne(filter, update)` call, your `update` portion must contain a valid top-level operator, e.g. `$set` or `$push`. Otherwise the entire document will be deleted and replaced with whatever `update` contains.

Use the `$set` operator to fix this:

```
db.collection("artists").updateOne(
    { _id: ObjectID(req.params.id) },
    { $set: { name: req.body.name } },
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/) the second argument to `updateOne` should be [update operator expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#id1) like `unset`, `set`, `rename`. The correct query syntax should be

```
db.collection("artists").updateOne({
        _id: ObjectID(req.params.id)
    }, {
        $set : { name: req.body.name }
    },
    function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.sendStatus(500);
        }
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Method  was changed as a side-effect of introducing the updateOne() method in addition to update() and updateMany() as somewhat of a safeguard to prevent user's from accidentally overriding an entire document.

```
db.collection("artists").updateOne(
{
  _id: ObjectID(req.params.id) },
  {
   $set: { name: req.body.name } 
  },
);
```

Or you use [replaceOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/)

```
db.collection("artists").replaceOne
   (
    { _id: ObjectID(req.params.id) }, { name: req.body.name }
   );
```